# How to use ST_Intersection?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, polygon, postgresql, intersection

Here's a quick summary about what I'm trying to do: I have 3 tables in Postgres, 'a' and 'b', each have a Polygon column, and 'c' has a Point column. What I'm trying to do here is to get the geometries intersections between 'a', 'b' and 'c', and to display such geometries on an OpenLayers vector layer.

I already know how to display any kind of geometry from a String in OpenLayers, but I'm having troubles with the PostGIS' ST_Intersection function, I'm doing this:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as inter from a, b;
```

where a.geom and b.geom are both the geometry columns, and I get this error message:

```
NOTICE:  TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between 515172 2.14408e+06, 497067 2.13373e+06 and 501321 2.13546e+06, 471202 2.14843e+06 500621 2.13576e+06 
ERROR:  GEOS Intersection() threw an error!
```

Also I tried to express the resultant geometry as text using ST_AsText like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as inter from a, b;
```

but it send me this error message:

```
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just want to get the Polygons' WKT to display it on OpenLayers, here's how I display a geometry from a WKT:

```
                    var in_options = {
                        'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                    }; 

                    var fea= new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(in_options).read(data); //data is the string with the WKT
                    vectorLayer.addFeatures([fea]); //this piece of code works great
                    map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```

UPDATE: I tried the next:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as intersect_ab FROM a INNER JOIN b ON 
ST_Intersection(a,b) WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom) 
AND ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t';
```

but I get the next error message:

```
ERROR: Function st_intersection(a,b) does not exist.
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I added the isvalid to verify only valid polygons are being evaluated, but it's telling the error is in the ST_Intersection(a,b), both a, b and c have the same SRID so I'm really confused, sorry if I'm asking too much, but I'm quite new with PostGIS so I hope I'm not bothering you a lot. Thanks.

Comment: What does `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();` return?

Comment: POSTGIS="1.4.0" GEOS="3.1.0-CAPI-1.5.0" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" USE_STATS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess would be that it fails if the intersection returns NULL. So you should add a where clause checking if there actually is an intersection before you try to create the WKT.

Comment: I tried this: SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as intersect_ab FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersection(a,b) WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom) AND ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t'; but it returned the same error : **ERROR: Function st_intersection(a, b) does not exist. HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. ** I'm really stuck at this one, if you can help me I will realy appreciate it.

Comment: Try summary(a.geom) and summary(b.geom) to investigate the values.

Comment: summary          
--------------------------
 
 Polygon[BS] with 1 rings
    ring 0 has 4 points
 
 
 Polygon[BS] with 1 rings
    ring 0 has 5 points
 
 
 Polygon[BS] with 1 rings
    ring 0 has 10 points

Comment: Yeah, it should be ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom) not ST_Intersection(a,b)

Answer (score 8):

The clue is

```
ERROR: Function st_intersection(a,b) does not exist.
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

As the error message says you can't use st_intersection in that way. Summarizing the other answers you should use something like this:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as intersect_ab 
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
WHERE ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t';
```

AFAIK there is no sense to use [st_overlaps](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Overlaps.html) and [st_intersects](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Intersects.html) in the same sentence as [they are pretty similar](http://selectoid.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/a-look-at-st_intersects-st_overlaps-and-st_intersection/).

Answer (score 4):

I test between different layer of polygons and it failed if there is at least an invalid geometry in one of the layer. Did you check the validity of your polygons using ST_isvalid(the_geom)? It may be the key.

Comment: I tried this: SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as intersect_ab FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersection(a,b) WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom) AND ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t';

but it returned the same error : **ERROR: Function st_intersection(a, b) does not exist. HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
** I'm really lost as to why it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) As intersect_ab
    FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersection(a,b)
    WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
    ;
```

[Source](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet)

Comment: I tried that too but it returns the same error message:

    HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: How about if you use "INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom)"?

Comment: It tells: ERROR: argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type geometry.

Comment: shizer... there must be something wrong with the data or something because this type of query works for me.

Comment: I added AND ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t'; at the end to only evaluate the valid geometries but it's telling me the error is in that st_intersection(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to exclude the invalid geometries but it didn't work, so in the end I had to delete every invalid geometry and then use this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as intersect_ab FROM a,b 
WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom) AND ST_isvalid(a.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(b.geom)='t';
```

As you can see I omitted the ST_Intersection(a,b) part, and this worked great, I'm kind of sad beacuse I couldn't find a way to exclude any invalid geometry from my select, anyway thanks to everyone for helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once.

```
<pre>NOTICE:  TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between xxx, xxxx and xxx, xxx  ERROR:  GEOS Intersection() threw an error!</pre>
```

I was able to resolve this error using this method.
- Use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)
- Add vector layer from your database
- Take the point from the error message and search for it in QGIS
  
"QuickWKT" (plugin) can be used to find it
- Then you will see the problem linestring
- Turn on edit mode
- Select "node tool" to show green node (node problem)
- Move node away from overlap node
- Save changes