# PostGIS Intersection and Summarise Attributes

Tags: postgis, sql

I am usually an ArcGIS desktop user, but keen to start using PostGIS more and I have a really big bit of processing to do. Not sure what functions to use, hopefully someone can help.

I have a polygon dataset (several million features), based on a type of landuse/ landcover classfication (20 categories). I have a number of regions in another dataset.

For each of the regions, I would like to know the area of each landcover classfication.

In ArcGIS (if it was a smaller dataset) I would imagine first adding the region to each of the polygons in the attribute table using a join. Then using "summarize" on the table by region and by landcover classification.

Not sure where to start doing this in PostGIS / SQL.

**Update:**

Wow thanks that has been a huge help.

It has been running a long time (44 hours!) and now I get:

```
NOTICE:  TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (coords
edited) and LINESTRING (coords edited) at (position edited)
ERROR:  GEOS Intersection() threw an error!

********** Error **********

ERROR: GEOS Intersection() threw an error!
SQL state: XX000
```

I assume this is a problem in the original data - just a case of reviewing the original data or can I first check the topology some how for the whole data?
Is there something about accepting certain errors / processing tolerances?

Comment: Quoting PostGIS docs (http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html): "If you encounter any strange error messages such as "GEOS Intersection() threw an error!" or "JTS Intersection() threw an error!" when calling PostGIS functions with valid input geometries, you likely found an error in either PostGIS or one of the libraries it uses, and you should contact the PostGIS developers.

Comment: ok, is there a way to evaluate the original data, should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes, you could open a new question. Have you checked this related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12451/how-to-use-st-intersection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have the following table layout

```
landcover(id,type,the_geom)
region(id,name,the_geom)
```

Area values per landcover type per region can be calculated using

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.the_geom, l.type, 
       Sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(l.the_geom,r.the_geom)))
FROM landcover l,
     region r
WHERE l.the_geom && r.the_geom
GROUP by r.id, r.name, r.the_geom, l.type
```

ST_Intersection is used to account for landcover polygons that are only partially within a region.

Comment: You may want to add "WHERE l.the_geom && r.the_geom" to the query to make use of spatial indexes.