# Problems with dividing multipolygons into polygons

Tags: shapefile, polygon, postgis-2.0, worldwind

I have a shapefile with countries boundaries downloaded from [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) and I am trying to upload it to PostGIS database with ogr2ogr. This file contains features of polygon and multipolygon types and because of that I cannot upload these features in one column.

I tried to divide the multipolygons into several polygons with QGIS and with python+fiona. But some countries got cut and have wrong boundaries.

[image: NASA WorldWind visualization]

What may cause that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to add `-nlt MULTIPOLYGON` to you ogr2ogr command to force a multipolygon output?

Comment: @thibautg Yes, I tried this. Then in code I extracted polygons from multipolygons to visualize this with WorldWind and got that problem again.

Comment: I didn't know WorldWind. It [seems very nice](https://goworldwind.org/demos/) though. Do you connect it directly to PostGIS or do you need to export the table to a file (for example a KML)?

Comment: @thibautg Yes, I directly connect to PostGIS with JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

To import the Shapefile to PostGIS:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=user dbname=db_name password=pw" -nln public.world_borders -nlt MULTIPOLYGON "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"
```

The Shapefile is imported as `MULTIPOLYGON`.

If you want to expode it to `POLYGON` in PostGIS, use `ST_Dump`:

```sql
SELECT 
  ogc_fid, 
  fips, 
  iso2, 
  iso3, 
  un, 
  name, 
  area, 
  pop2005, 
  region, 
  subregion, 
  lon, 
  lat, 
  ((ST_Dump(wkb_geometry)).geom)::geometry(Polygon,4326) geom
FROM public.world_borders;
```

Edit: this does not work because the initial Shapefile is corrupted. I've run QGIS's "Check geometry validity" tool and here is the output:

[image: Check geometry validity tool screenshot]

Try contacting the creator of the file to get a repaired version.

Comment: I did so, but got the same result.

Comment: I've opened the above query in QGIS via DB Manager and I don't see the same artifacts as you do. Maybe a problem with your viewer (WorldWind)?

Comment: I've opened it in QGIS and didn't see any artifacts too. But I noticed that when I retrieve polygons in Java some of them has unequal first and last points. I tried simply add first point at the end but it had no effect.

Comment: Indeed it seems that some of the polygons are not valid (I ran `SELECT
  a.*,
  ST_IsValid(geom)
FROM
(
SELECT 
  ogc_fid, 
  fips, 
  iso2, 
  iso3, 
  un, 
  name, 
  area, 
  pop2005, 
  region, 
  subregion, 
  lon, 
  lat, 
  ((ST_Dump(wkb_geometry)).geom)::geometry(Polygon,4326) geom
FROM public.world_borders
) a
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom)`

Comment: Maybe try [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) like that (very slow though): `SELECT 
  ogc_fid, 
  fips, 
  iso2, 
  iso3, 
  un, 
  name, 
  area, 
  pop2005, 
  region, 
  subregion, 
  lon, 
  lat, 
  ST_MakeValid(((ST_Dump(wkb_geometry)).geom))::geometry(Polygon,4326) geom
FROM public.world_borders;`

Comment: Tried. That didn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe try to first MakeValid the multipolygon: `((ST_Dump(ST_MakeValid(wkb_geometry))).geom)::geometry(Polygon,4326) geom` OR add a buffer of 0.0 with  `((ST_Dump(ST_Buffer(wkb_geometry,0.0))).geom)::geometry(Polygon,4326) geom` like suggested [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15286/ring-self-intersections-in-postgis)

Comment: Tried both, no effect.

Comment: I've run out of ideas to repair the geometries. The original Shapefile is damaged. I've updated my answer.