# Fixing polygon with ring self-intersection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-2, self-intersection, ring

When I polygonize a raster, I very often have 'pixels' holes/interior ring that touches exterior ring.

An example:

```
POLYGON((5 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0, 5 0, 3 3, 5 6, 7 3, 5 0))
```

[image]

It's defined as an invalid geometry in the OGC geometry specifications.

In QGIS, how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution here but for PostGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15301/93097 and I've tested it in Spatialite/[Virtual layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_db_manager.html#dbmanager), and it works.

Bellow the code I used with a shapefile 'my_layer' with one field `"DN"` and wrote in [the DB Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_db_manager.html#dbmanager):

```sql
SELECT "DN", ST_Buffer(geometry, 0.0) as geometry
FROM my_layer;
```

In the SQL query `SELECT [...] FROM [...];` :

- `"DN"` as mentionned above is the field of my layer. It's a common field [that contains raster informations after vectorization, stands for **D**igital **N**umber](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_exercise.html#vectorizing-the-raster). I put it in the query in order to get my attributes with the new virtual layer. If you have more/different fields, just write `"my_field1", "my_field2", "my_field3"` as in a SQL SELECT query instead of `"DN"`.
- `geometry` is the default field name for geometry in a QGIS shapefile or memory layer.
- `ST_Buffer(geometry, 0.0)` : creates a buffer of 0, so a buffer with no distance, and it rewrites the polygon definition (vertices order) and fix self-intersections.

Comment: Hi, where do you use this code ?

Comment: WHat is DN? can you explain the context?

Comment: All the answers of your comments are already in my answer.

Comment: Hi, what is postGis, a pluggin? what is DN, do you use the field calculator?  sorry it is very blur to me I am new to QGIS...

Comment: So, I advise you to search on internet a little about SQL and databases (with spatial extensions).

Comment: "Use the forum search feature!" is not an answer. What is the meaning of "DN" and why have you included it? If it's just a field relevant to your database and not a part of the answer, why included it?

Comment: @MrYellow: about my previous answer to Robagb, for me all is in the answer and my intention regarding my advice was kind. About the meaning of `"DN"`, I specified it just above the code and it's a field of my layer. It's not useful to fix the polygon geometry but useful to retrieve my layer attributes in the new geometry fixed virtual layer.

Comment: Probably helpful to remove from your example the unrelated off-topic field which is obviously causing confusion.

Comment: @MrYellow: I understand your opinion, but in my question : "When I polygonize a raster", so in the same case of me, a user will have a high probability to have the same field. I explained after your comment why I let the field and avoid questions like : "how I get my attributes back".

Comment: Fair, I'm usually wrong when confident. ;-)